# Android activity stack button go back

Tags: java, android, stack

I have a problem, my app has 3 activities:
Home activity >  Activity 1 > Activity 2
when I go to activity 2 and back to home activity with my back buttons all activities I been to stay in stack so if I use back button on the lower nav menu it takes me to all activities I have been to and I want it just to go back to parent activity but if i use

`android:noHistory:"true";`
or
`finish()`

it makes my activity close the app when i go back

this is code for the back button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(InstitutionActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`for the intent before calling startActivity. This should clear the stack.

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Yeah this worked for me, thanks,  just had to play little bit to find right place for it.